# Pinax import error

Tags: django, pinax

Receiving this when attempting to run Pinax 0.7rc1 basic_project for the first time.

"Exception Value: cannot import name messages"

Pinax installs Django 1.0.3 and I don't think this version has the messages module.

Any help?

http://dpaste.com/525105/

Django 1.0.3
[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://pinaxproject.com/docs/dev/faq/

**Does Pinax work on Django 1.1?**

> Yes. Pinax 0.7 ships with Django 1.0.4
>   by default. Django 1.1 came too late
>   in our 0.7 release cycle. However, we
>   tested it on Django 1.1 to ensure it
>   works and it works well. To use Django
>   1.1 in your Pinax project simply follow our installation documentation
>   and once you are in the virtual
>   environment run:
>
> ```
> pip install -U Django==1.1.1
> ```
>
> This will install Django 1.1.1 over
>   1.0.4.

**Does Pinax work on Django 1.2?**

> Yes and no. Our stable release 0.7.X
>   (at 0.7.2) does not support Django
>   1.2. We will attempt to make 0.7.3 compatible to run on Django 1.2.
>   Installing Django 1.2 over 1.0 that
>   ships with 0.7 will work the same way
>   as seen above. We hope to release
>   0.7.3 soon. There are no timelines.
>
> On the other hand our development
>   version of Pinax will ship with Django
>   1.2. Stay tuned for more news regarding the releases of 0.9.

## New in Django 1.2: The messages framework was added.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/messages/